# Django file upload: permission problem, error 13

Tags: django, file, permissions, upload

I'm creating a django module to upload files, and i'm following this django documentation:  [FileUploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

But when it executes 

`destination=destination = open('/media/name.txt','wb+')`

it throws this error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/name.txt'

My settings are:

1. a folder 'media' in root of django project
2. in settings.py MEDIA_ROOT is /home/user/...django_project_folder/media/ and MEDIA_URL is  http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/
3. folder media has 777 as permissions, and executing ls -l media's owner is the same that runs the project (checked through lsof -i command)

Due these settings, i consider very strange this error.

Some help?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
open('media/name.txt','wb+')
```

insead of:

```
open('/media/name.txt','wb+')
```